# input:invalid is not working with formcontrol

Tags: html, css, angular, input, css-selectors

I have an input that has a `FormControl` and I want it to work with `:invalid` i.e.

`scss`

```
input:invalid {
   background-color: red;
}
```

`html`

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="NameCtrl">
```

but it is not working with it. Although it is working with `required` i.e.

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" required>
```

How to decorate `input` field with error styles with `FormControl`. Any idea, solution, or workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It will work if you add validator on template:<input type="text" [formControl]="NameCtrl" required>

Comment: Yeah it will work but ease of using `FormControl` will be dead. Also what about other validations like `min`, `max` etc.

Comment: Actually when you add required directive in template it will register validation with formControl.Same goes for min max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invalid pseudo selector works only for basic HTML validation, for example.

I enter 'hello' as the value for an input field with type as `email` then only invalid will work.

more details here for [invalid pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid)

When dealing with angular `:invalid` is pretty useless, instead use the classes inserted by angular form validations, as shown below!

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-template-driven-form-validation-nxfgfp)